# Erroraction not working with multiple commands

Tags: powershell, nuget

If I run

`Remove-Item .\somefolder -force -Recurse -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'`

nothing will be displayed if the folder doesn't exist but if I run

`Remove-Item .\somefolder -force -Recurse -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'; otherCommand`

I get "Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'the path' because it does not exist."

How to suppress the error?

**Edit:** I found out the problem happens only when I run the commands from the Visual Studio Package Manager console.

Comment: can u explain more ? what is the other command becus i tested it . this is work completly without error

Comment: @arashzgh You are right, I edited my question

Comment: i write answers and it's work fine just put your path in "./path" in duble cot

Answer (score 0):

if you use dublecot "./somefolder" it's work fine without any error :

```
Remove-Item ".\Somefolder" -force -Recurse -erroraction 'silentlycontinue';somecommand
```

or use single cot :

```
Remove-Item '.\Somefolder' -force -Recurse -erroraction 'silentlycontinue';somecommand
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the error action preference for multiple commands then
you can set erroractionpreference variable before executing those commands:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
```

note: I am assuming that your other command is the reason for error